# C pthread_creat() output repeated numbers

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

C Code:

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void *helloFunc(void *ptr)
{
    int *data;
    data = (int *)ptr;
    printf("I am thread %d\n", *data);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t hThread[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        pthread_create(&hThread[i], NULL, helloFunc, (void *)&i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        pthread_join(hThread[j], NULL);
}
```

I run the code on Ubuntu20.04, and find that the outputs are like

```
I am thread 2
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
I am thread 3
```

```
I am thread 1
I am thread 3
I am thread 4
I am thread 2
```

```
I am thread 3
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
I am thread 4
```

I wonder why the output has some repeated numbers instead of a random list of 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: There is only one `i` variable. So which value each thread sees depends on when it runs relative to which iteration the parent thread is up to. That is determined by the OS scheduling. To get your intended behaviour declare an array and pass a different array element to each thread.

Comment: @kaylum I wonder if there is "one `i` variable" at all. Isn't the lifetime of  `i` limited to the loop without any warantee that it still exists when the thread function is executed? It might actually be `j` that is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the address of `i` to every thread. When the threads dereference it to read it, it may have been increased 0 or more times in the main thread so what you read in the threads is indeterminable.

You could create an `int[4]` array and pass the unique address of each individual `int` to the started thread instead - or you could package the `pthread_t` and its data in a `struct` to store everything connected to a certain thread in one place.

Example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    pthread_t th;
    int i;
    /* add more data fields to the struct if needed */
} threadinfo;

void *helloFunc(void *ptr)
{
    threadinfo* ti = (threadinfo*) ptr;
    printf("I am thread %d\n", ti->i);
}

int main(void)
{
    threadinfo hThread[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        hThread[i].i = i;         /* fill in the data fields */

        /* and pass the address of the threadinfo struct as a parameter here */
        pthread_create(&hThread[i].th, NULL, helloFunc, (void *)&hThread[i]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        pthread_join(hThread[j].th, NULL);
}
```